# Relational modelling question

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship, relational, relational-model

We have three entities called `Product`, `ProductType`, and `ProductCategory`.

Let's pretend we have three kinds of `ProductType`: `Book`, `Music`, and `Video`.

We have three different `ProductCategory`'s for `Book`: `Fiction`, `Novel`, `Technical`.

Three different `ProductCategory`'s for `Music`: `Rock`, `Jazz`, `Pop`.

And we have three different `ProductCategory`'s for `Video`: `Fiction`, `Comic`, `Drama`.

A `Product` has a `ProductType` and can have many `ProductCategory`'s. But its `ProductCategory`'s should match its `ProductType`. For example, if its `ProductType` is `Book`, it can only take `Fiction`, `Novel`, and `Technical` as `ProductCategory`'s.

Is it possible to model this schema with this restriction (i.e. that `ProductCategory`'s for a `Product` should match with its `ProductType`) without using application code or triggers, etc -- Just using tables, foreign keys, etc.

How would you model this?

Comment: @Ninja: broken link corrected, waiting for your responses to outstanding questions.

Answer (score 3):

## PRODUCT_TYPE

- PRODUCT_TYPE_ID (pk)
- PRODUCT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION

## PRODUCT_CATEGORY

- PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID (pk)
- PRODUCT_TYPE_ID (fk to `PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID` )
- PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION

## PRODUCT

- PRODUCT_ID (pk)
- PRODUCT_TYPE_ID (fk to `PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID` )

## PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MAP

- PRODUCT_ID (pk, fk to `PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID`)
- PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID (pk, fk to `PRODUCT_CATEGORY.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID`)
- PRODUCT_TYPE_ID (pk, fk to both `PRODUCT.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID` ***and*** `PRODUCT_CATEGORY.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID`)

Comment: Wow, could you make that font a bit bigger, please? I'm having a hard time reading it :-)

Comment: Product(1, 1) has ProductType(1, Music). We also have ProductType(2, Video). We have ProductCategory(1, 2, Drama) for Video and ProductCategory(2, 1, Jazz) for Music. Now we can have ProductCategoryMap(1, 1, 2) which is invalid.

Comment: In `ProductCategoryMap(1, 1, 2)`, `PRODUCT_TYPE_ID` is `2`. We have a row in `PRODUCT_TYPE` with `PRODUCT_ID 2` -- i.e `(2, Video)` -- and we have a row in `PRODUCT_CATEGORY` that its `PRODUCT_TYPE_ID` is also `2` -- e.g. `(1, 2, Drama)`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Bytecode Ninja: I'm missing how that is invalid - the type and category matches between the PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MAP and PRODUCT_CATEGORY; the type matches between PRODUCT and PRODUCT_CATEGORY_MAP.

Comment: Only `Video` products can have `Drama`. Now we have a `Music` product that has the category `Drama`. Mmm... where did your other comment go? :D

Comment: @Bytecode Ninja: I corrected the typo in my answer to point to the PRODUCT table.  I wouldn't make fun of those who try to help, when they have difficulty understanding what you're trying to communicate.

Comment: This still seems to have the same problem as before.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy, it is a simple two-level classifcation issue.  in your app, you need two *separate* drop downs, the ProductCategory is filled *after* the ProductType has been chosen.

One clarification: Your statement *"A Product has a ProductType and can have many ProductCategory's"* is contradicted by your description.  A Product can have only one Product Category (Fiction, Jazz), which is based on a ProductType(Book, Music).

There is no need for surrogate keys here (there may be in other modelling requirements), they are merely redundant here.  For simple classifications like this, CHAR(1) or (2) is much better, user and developer friendly (when you are scanning output, you know "B" means "Book", etc), as well as being faster than any numeric key (except of course tinyint).

There is no "trick" here, it is straight Normalisation, which supports the rules you identified.

[**Link to Product Classification**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Product%20Classification.pdf)

I do not understand the need for a "map" table.

I have provided a surrogate key for Product, but of course you need other keys, in order to implement reasonable constraints.

**Responses to Comments**

Ok, so your requirements are not clear, and it appears they are now changing.  When you answer my specific questions in the comments, the model required to support your requirement will be easy.  In order to assist, I have published two possibilities.  Of course it is incomplete, pending your answers:

[**Link to Two Possible Models**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Product%20Classification%202.pdf)

The "tightness" of your control re administrator vs users seems to be very loose. Please choose one of the following, so that we can progress and close the question:

1. The Product.ProductType is set by the admin.  This allows the admin and users to choose Any of the valid ProductCategories for the Product.ProductType for whatever use they have.
2. For each Product, the admin chooses the ProductType **and** a subset of ProductCategories (from the list of ProductCategories that are valid for the Product.ProductType).  The users can *then* use only the ProductCategories **chosen** by the admin for the Product, for whatever use they have.

Respond please, and then I will publish the final version.

Comment: There could be a product like "Star Wars" that's a Movie, and has two categories: 'Vintage' and 'Sci-Fi'. Or a movie can have both 'Horror' and 'Sci-Fi' categories.

Comment: So now you are saying, a Product can have more than one category.  if so, who picks which category the product is sold as; and how (what data do they use) do they make that decision ?  Are you saying: A product has one ProductType; one ProductCategory; EACH of which is chosen from a set of valid ProductType-ProductCategories ?

Comment: Think of a ProductCategory as a tag or label. But when a Product is Music, it can only be labeled with certain labels that are valid for Music. And these are used when an admin or operator ads new products to the system. So he wants to add 'Star Wars', then he puts it in the Video ProductType, and then the list of valid categories for Video show up and he can associate one or more of those categories with the product. Having said that I think the schema that you have provided solves this problem. It might just need some minor modifications. I'll double check that and let you know.

Comment: No I think your solution only works when a Product can have at most one ProductCategory.

Comment: Yes, as identified in my post.  That's what you identified in your initial "requirement".  Now you are asking for something else.  I have asked clarifying questions.  If and when you supply answers to those questions, I will be able to provide the change model.  So far (unless you change your "requirement" again) ProductType & ProducCategory are "right"; the relation between them and Product is "pending", awaiting your clarification.  It is not possible to supply a model to someone who does not know their requirement.

Comment: I do not need descriptions, I know all that; I need specific answers to my specific questions in comment 2 above: (1) WHEN the admin adds the Star Wars movie, OF the several categories available to them for movie, HOW (on what basis) do they choose ONE category.  (2) OR, do they assign more than one category to Star Wars, and if so (3) how MANY.

Comment: "That's what you identified in your initial "requirement". Now you are asking for something else." I haven't changed my question and my initial requirement was: "A Product has a ProductType and can have many ProductCategory's".

Comment: Never mind.  What about the remaining specific questions in the Comments ?